# Automatically Assign Datatypes to Dataframe? (Python - Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, types

I've been provided a SQL table that has all 188 columns set to nvarchar. When bringing this table into Python via Pandas, all the column's datatypes become "objects".

I'm creating a machine learning model in Python and in order to create proper features, it makes sense to give these columns the proper datatypes. e.g. columns with numbers should be INT

I will note, that I cannot modify the SQL table, thus I'm left to fixing the data in python.

Instead of going one by one and assigning data types to 188 columns, is there a way to auto-assign the datatype based off the data in the column?

Comment: First read the columns and then you can use int() if they are numbers.

Comment: some are int, some are dates, some are textual flags, I'm trying to systematically have the data types chosen based off the distinct data in each column.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more pythonic way of doing this, but a common pattern across other languages is to use a `try/catch` to test converting the value to different types until it is successful. For example, `try` to convert it to a date, and then `catch` the appropriate exception (generally `ValueError`) with a `pass`. Repeat for converting to int, and any other datatypes.

For example, the code below will test for `int` and `float` datatypes:

```
# Define the values
value = '12.3'
datatype = 'nvarchar'  # Default datatype

# Test for int
try:
    int(value)
    datatype = 'int'
except ValueError:
    pass

# Test for float
try:
    float(value)
    datatype = 'float'
except ValueError:
    pass


# ... And so on with try/except

# Output the datatype
print(datatype)
```

Comment: how would i apply this logic to a dataframe?

Comment: That's where things get tricky, and you need to semi-understand the data in your dataframe. If the data is 100% unknown, you'd need to iterate through every value in each column to ensure that every bit of data conforms to the datatype. For example, if row one has a value of "1", that could be an int, but it could also be a string that happens to contain only a number. You'd need to view other values to make sure that all values in the column are ints. If you think you can get away with just evaluating the first X values of each column, then you can save time and simply do that.